# Content type always use view

Tags: 7, views

So I have a content type called `MyContentType` and two views: `mycontents` and `mycontent/%`.

`mycontents` shows all `MyContentType`s with a pager. `mycontent/%` shows a single `MyContentType` based on node id.

How do I make it so when clicking on a content's header in `mycontents` (or any other way of displaying `MyContentType`) takes it through to `mycontent/[nid]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Views 'rewrite output' feature for the `Field: Title` field on your `mycontents` view.

First, make sure you have added the `Content: NID` field to your view.  If you don't want this to be visible on your View, you can 'Exclude it from display` as noted in the graphic below.

[image: Exclude from display]

You will also need to reorder your views fields to ensure `Content:NID` is listed before your title so you can access it in the next step.

[image]

It's very important to to note that the `Content: Nid` field is *above* the `Content: Title` field.

Next, edit `Content: Title` and scroll down to and open the 'Rewrite Results' section.

Note: You may need to uncheck the 'Link this field to the original piece of content' checkbox for the `Content: Title` field.

In the 'Rewrite Results' section, check the box titled 'Output this field as a link.'  In this section, if you scroll down, you will see a link titled 'Replacement Patterns.'  This is where we will get the variables we need for our URL.

In the 'Link Path' box, enter your destination URL: `mycontent/[nid]`

[image]

Don't forget to save your view, but your titles should now be linked properly.

Comment: I think you may just be my favourite person. This worked a treat! Thankyou!